# How to ignore "Failed to get properties: Access denied"

Tags: unix, service, status

When I am trying to get the service status, I see some errors. I need to redirect them. I have tried `>,2>` and other redirect options, but no luck.

I need to execute this command without sudo and root user.

```
mouli@XXXXXXXXXX ~ $ systemctl status consul 
Failed to get properties: Access denied

mouli@XXXXXXXXXX ~ $ echo $?
1

mouli@XXXXXXXXXX ~ $ systemctl status consul > /dev/null 2 >& 1
Failed to get unit for PID 2: Access denied
Failed to get properties: Access denied

mouli@XXXXXXXXXX ~ $ systemctl status consul 2> /dev/null
Failed to get properties: Access denied

mouli@XXXXXXXXXX ~ $ systemctl status consul > /dev/null
Failed to get properties: Access denied
```

Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
systemctl status consul |grep Main > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This will create a file called `out` which will have both stderr and stdout.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Indeed, i need to do grep operation on it as well like below,

`mouli@XXXXXXX $ systemctl status consul |grep Main &> /dev/null
Failed to get properties: Access denied`


Is there any way to ignore errors

Comment: Ignore errors as in? Do you want the errors to be written in a separate file? And not have them on stdout?

Comment: stdout[/dev/null]

Comment: mouli@XXXXXXX $ systemctl status consul |grep Main > /dev/null 2>&1
Failed to get properties: Access denied

I see the same errors.